# C# Marshal / Pinvoke CBitmap?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I cannot figure out how to marshal a C++ CBitmap to a C# Bitmap or Image class.

My import looks like this:

[DllImport(@"test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetBitmap(System.IntPtr hwnd, int nBMPWIDTH, int nBMPHEIGHT);

The H file section looks like:

Cbitmap* GetBitmap（HWND hwnd,int nBMPWIDTH,int nBMPHEIGHT）；

How do I go about converting the Cbitmap into something I can display in C#?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The closest API in the .NET Framework is Image.FromHbitmap, but this would require you to extract the HBITMAP from the CBitmap, which you can't do in C# (at least not without knowing the internals of CBitmap).  If it's possible for you to modify your C++ GetBitmap function to return the HBITMAP rather than the CBitmap wrapper, that would be the easiest solution.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: Seconded.  You'll have to get the HBITMAP from the CBitmap, which you'll have to do in C++.  You technically can marshal a class, but you'd have to know it's Exact memory layout.

Comment: I do not have access to the c++ dll source. What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Create a small C++ function as follows: HBITMAP GetHandle(CBitmap* pBitmap) { return (HBITMAP)( * pBitmap); }. Then P/Invoke this, passing your CBitmap IntPtr. The returned IntPtr is the HBITMAP. (The reason for still having the CBitmap * is so you can defer freeing it until you've finished with the HBITMAP; otherwise the CBitmap destructor will trash the handle for you I believe.)

Comment: Would I create this C++ function in managed CLR c++? or win32? Thank you.

Comment: I was thinking native C++.  But you're probably right that it could also be done in C++/CLI, in which case you wouldn't need to P/Invoke the wrapper because it would be a .NET-to-.NET call (and the transition to native code would happen within your C++/CLI assembly).